# Non-blocking socket writes in Java versus blocking socket writes

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, nio

Why would someone prefer blocking writes over non-blocking writes? My understanding is that you would only want blocking write if you want to make sure the other side got the TCP packet once the write method returned, but I am not even sure that's possible. You would have to flush and flush would have to flush the *underlying operating system write socket buffer*. So is there any disadvantage of non-blocking socket writes? Does having a large underlying write socket buffer a bad idea in terms of performance? My understanding is that the smaller the underlying socket write buffer the more likely you will hit slow/buggy client and have to drop/queue packets in the application level while the underlying socket buffer is full and isWritable() is returning false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My understanding is that you would only want blocking write if you want to make sure the other side got the TCP packet once the write method returned

Your understanding is incorrect. It doesn't ensure that.

Blocking writes block until all the data has been transferred to the socket send buffer, from where it is transferred asynchronously to the network. If the reader is slow, his socket receive buffer will fill up, which will eventually cause your socket send buffer to fill up, which will cause a blocking write to block, blocking the whole thread. Non-blocking I/O gives you a way to detect and handle that situation.

Comment: So making it short: blocking write you will block, non-blocking write you can use the isWritable() call to find out if the underlying socket write buffer is full and decide what to do without blocking. So the (dangerous) answer to my question is: non-blocking writes are better than blocking writes. You have more control and the same performance.

Comment: @achrisapotek To be precise, isWritable() means that the last select() triggered on an OP_WRITE event, *at which time* there was room in the socket send buffer. The answer to your question is that non-blocking writes don't block. Whether that's better depends on your needs.

Comment: If there was room when OP_WRITE was triggered you will have room when isWritable() returns true later inside your loop. Unless there is another thread writing which makes very little sense. It is hard for me to imagine a situation where blocking writes are preferable. Of course you can always come up with one, but non-blocking writes gives you the option to decide what to do: wait (block), queue packets, drop packets or kill client. That's much better!!!

Comment: @chrisapotek. (1) there was room in the buffer (2) OP_WRITE triggered the select() (3) isWritable() returned true (4) you entered that loop (5) the first write filled the socket send buffer (5) there was more data left in the ByteBuffer so (6) you iterated the loop again, the write returned zero, the same amount of data as at (5) is still there, so (7) you iterated the loop again ... The situation where blocking writes are preferable is when you have a thread per client.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with non blocking writes is that you may not have anything useful to do if the write is incomplete.  You can end up with loops like

```
// non-blocking write
while(bb.remaining() > 0) sc.write(bb);
```

OR

```
// blocking write
sc.write(bb);
```

The first can burn CPU and the second might be more desirable.

The big problem is reads.  Once you decide whether you want blocking or non-blocking reads, your writes have to be the same.  Unfortunately there is no way to make them different.  If you want non-blocking reads, you have to have non-blocking writes.

Comment: `select()` and `OP_WRITE` are the solutions to 'not having anything to do'.

Comment: Using the Selector for non-blocking write is potentially more efficient. However IMHO it should be so rare, it may not matter.

Comment: @EJP: When the underlying write socket buffer is FULL and you have the OP_WRITE registered, does the selector select the writable key even thought isWritable() will return false, putting yourself in a loop like Peter was saying? Or is it smart enough just to select the key when space in the buffer becomes available?

Comment: @chrisapotek that's all a contradiction in terms. select() returning on OP_WRITE *means* there is room in the socket send buffer. Nothing else.

Comment: @EJP: So the loop Peter described cannot happen, because the key will not be selected with a full buffer. If you call isWritable() and it returns true you are good to write, otherwise you have to queue or drop, you decide.

Comment: @chrisapotek The buffer can be full after one or more iterations of the loop. You also need to be clear that isWritable() doesn't itself look at the buffer state. Only the preceding select() does that.

Comment: @EJP Very true and thank you very much. You can rely on the write operation to detect a partial write on a full underlying buffer. I got confused with the isWritable(). If isWritable() returns false the key was selected on some other operation besides OP_WRITE and you should refrain from writing on that iteration. You can decide to queue or drop. Most of the time you will be reading and writing on the same selector, so if you did not read anything you do not have to write anything, it does not matter the state of the buffer and you probably did not get selected anyways.

Comment: @EJP: A common solution: only register OP_WRITE when you get a full buffer, so you can wait for room. While you don't get a full buffer just write at will whenever you like it, in other words whenever you read something. Agree? :)

Comment: @chrisapotek That's what OP_WRITE is *for.* It's not just a 'common solution', it is the design intent.

Comment: @EJP It 'makes sense' to be deceived that you should register OP_WRITE whenever you want to write, agree?

Comment: @chrisapotek I don't know what you mean by 'makes sense to be deceived'. There's nothing to be deceived about. You can use `OP_WRITE` as a way to enqueue your writes if you wish, or you can just try the write whenever you have data and use it as an escape hatch for when the buffer fills. Both patterns are equally valid.