# Java: API to find if all the bytes written to Non-Blocking TCP SocketChannel has been sent to receiver?

Tags: java, sockets, nonblocking, tcpsocket

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086930/non-blocking-socket-writes-in-java-versus-blocking-socket-writes) is a similar answer, though is not what I exactly want. I want to do following two things:

1. I want to find out if all the bytes have been sent to the receiver?
2. Also I want to know the current remaining capacity of output buffer of the socket, without attempting a write to it?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your numbered points in order:

1. The only way you can find that out is by having the peer application acknowledge the receipt.
2. There isn't such an API in Java. As far as I know there isn't one at the BSD sockets layer either, but I'm not familiar with the outer limits of Linux where they may have introduced some such thing.

Comment: Is there an simpler API, just to check(boolean response) if the buffer is empty or not?

Comment: There is no such API in any form whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know.  The data is potentially buffered by the OS and TCP/IP stack, and there is no method for determining if it has actually been placed on the wire.  Even knowing it was placed on the wire is no guarantee of anything as it could be lost in transit.

For UDP you will never know if the data was received by the destination system unless you write a UDP-based protocol such that the remote system acknowledges the data.

For TCP the protocol stack will ensure that your code is notified if the data is lost in transit, but it may be many seconds before you receive confirmation.